# css and js not working in cakephp after enable mod_rewrite module?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

css , js and any redirect function not working in cakephp after enable mod_rewrite module.If I understand correctly  there may be two reason

```
1) Html helper not working and ,
2) There is problem by that anything could not redirect to webroot but i dont know about tha problem .
```

Is there anyone who has faced this problem or can help me out ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I need more informations for help youe. First, what means 'not working'? An error? Warning? Incorrect url? PLeas edit your question and put more details :)

Answer (score 0):

faced it once but solved the issue by checking AllowOverride rewrite module

please check if the httpd.conf file if the setting for directory is 
`AllowOverride None` then set it to `AllowOverride All` and restart apache and check